# Can I Auto Tile A Mesh With Tiles I've Made?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a dungeon layout and was wondering if there was an easier way to tile in the whole floor? I was about to do it by hand but thought there must be a way to do this, if not I'll just go ahead and do it by hand. Thanks! I'll obviously have to scale down the tiles, just made them this large so you could see.

Alternatively, is there any way to array multiple objects randomly instead of just one?

[image: Tiling]